# Necessity of Azure blob storage

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-pipelines

Could anyone please help me in understanding necessity of Azure blob or Datalake store.

I went through some blogs in microsoft saying to pull incremental data from source systems in form of csv files and store them in blob or datalakestore, and from blob/datalake store data should be pushed to azure DWH stage and then to datamart.

I am confused why do I need to generate csv and to use Azure Blob. As we can directly pull incremntal data and load into Azure DWH Stage.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything you don't want to do ;).  It's hard to say with precision as you didn't post the blog links, but generally there has been a trend (meaning many, but not necessarily everyone does it) to land raw telemetry-like data into cheap storage first and then "cook"/"scrub" it into higher-value data stores (that may also cost more).  There's also been work with the gen2 storage model in SQL DW to improve the price/perf of storing data (where it is storing things compressed in blob storage for you).  The key driver in all of these is cost vs. time-to-value on your data.  If your problem space works fine by landing the data directly in SQL DW or similar in Azure, you are welcome to do so.  If your data volume is so big you don't want it all in SQL DW (for cost or management reasons), then the model of using storage first may be beneficial to you.  I hope that gives you some more detail to help in your design decisions